# Why does thread go to sleep mode C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code that was running for about 2 hours. After that the program stopped to answer and I paused it in VS and checked on which line it was executing. I stopped in the Parallel statement and said something about "waiting on thread to join and stop sleep".

It's obvious that my multithreading experience is small so I have no idea why this happend.
I thought that the thread thats enter the while will be isolated and waiting for all other threads that starts in the foreach.

```
while (true)
        {
        Parallel.ForEach(servers, server => // It stopped here
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Checking: {0} Thread: {1}", server.Hostname, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            try
            {
               // Do some network stuff
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        });
}
```

Update 1

Do some network stuff is makeing some UDP sending and receiving with a timeout on 1500 ms. I also have some DB stuff based on Entity Framework here. So it's probably much that can go wrong. However I still unsure what can cause it. If the sockets (both my UDP stuff and DB stuff) are running and exceed the timeout they will rise an exception that will be "handled"

Isn't that enough? Can I set some sort of timeout for the complete thread. If it hasn't joined for 5000 ms kill it?

Comment: Ok, I don't get it. Will the socket start some more threads? Isn't the threadpool dedicated to my program or is it shared along .NET?

Comment: yes, the thread-pool is per-process, so is dedicated to your program; however, if some of the "Do some network stuff" can block indefinitely, that will stop the entire `Parallel.ForEach` indefinitely. We can't see what "Do some network stuff" does, so we can't comment on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Do some network stuff" would be the first thing I looked at (in particular: is there any chance it can block indefinitely - maybe a `Read` without timeout on a stream that isn't sending but isn't closed). If any of the "Do some network stuff" code blocks, that will block the entire `Parallel.ForEach`, as it doesn't return from `.ForEach` until *every* item has completed.

Finding the `Parallel.ForEach` waiting on a join is not unexpected (`Parallel.ForEach` *is* a split and join, after all) - the important question is: *what else is happening*, i.e. what are the *other* threads doing.

However, I would also want to ask whether it is possible somebody simply pressed <kbd>pause</kbd> on the keyboard (which pauses console output), or had accidentally click-dragged on the console area (which can enter the copy/paste mode, which again pauses console output).

Comment: I updated my question with some more info about the mystic network stuff ;-)

Comment: @SimonEdström with the update, then it comes down again to: what were the other threads doing. To debug this, you will need to look at more than just the primary thread.

Comment: Ok, but can I assume that this error could happend even if I wasn't starting a lots of threads?

Comment: @Simon when debugging threading code, you can't *assume* anything. You need to find out for sure. But: it shouldn't just stop spontaneously. There's nothing obviously wrong with the loop, so *something* is wrong. It *could* be a framework bug, or it *could* (more likely, perhaps?) be something that unexpectedly made your code stall...

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting this to only take a handful of seconds, run the code without the `Parallel.ForEach` and then you'll be able to easily see what's blocking as it'll all be on your main thread.

If you're doing this on VS2010 then you could also see what's going on by using the "parallel stacks" debug window in Visual Studio. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998398.aspx

If you have no experience with multi-threaded programming then I would start with a simple and standard `Thread`-based program and get familiar with the debugging tools (you will need the threads debug pane, for example) before you start debugging things with the Task Parallel Library (`Parallel.[...]`).